# WooCommerce Multi Select for Single Product Field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add the list box on the single product page, I was wondering no option for multiselect in woocommerce, For `get_option` fields woocommerce supporting multiselect but for `post_meta` woocommerce support only single select, Not sure is there any limitation in woocommerce or i could miss something to get multiselect? Here is the below code i tried

```
 function create_multiselect() { 

    woocommerce_wp_select(array(
                'id' => 'newoptions',
                'class' => 'newoptions',
                'label' => __('Testing Multiple Select', 'woocommerce'),
                'options' => array(
                    '1' => 'User1',
                    '2' => 'User2',
                    '3' => 'User3',
                ))
            );

    }

    add_action("woocommerce_product_options_pricing","create_multiselect");
```

Any Suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`woocommerce_wp_select()` function does not support multiselect, you can open the `wc-meta-box-functions.php` file in `/woocommerce/includes/admin` directory to see the default behavior.

But what's stopping you to create your own function that will be based on the default Woo function, and add the required features, or even change the default function ( but still, modifying the plugin files is not the best practice ). Here's an example of how to write a new function with multiple support, the only changes from original are added support for name and multiple attributes, and different logic for the selected items ( since post meta is now an array ).

```
function woocommerce_wp_select_multiple( $field ) {
    global $thepostid, $post, $woocommerce;

    $thepostid              = empty( $thepostid ) ? $post->ID : $thepostid;
    $field['class']         = isset( $field['class'] ) ? $field['class'] : 'select short';
    $field['wrapper_class'] = isset( $field['wrapper_class'] ) ? $field['wrapper_class'] : '';
    $field['name']          = isset( $field['name'] ) ? $field['name'] : $field['id'];
    $field['value']         = isset( $field['value'] ) ? $field['value'] : ( get_post_meta( $thepostid, $field['id'], true ) ? get_post_meta( $thepostid, $field['id'], true ) : array() );

    echo '<p class="form-field ' . esc_attr( $field['id'] ) . '_field ' . esc_attr( $field['wrapper_class'] ) . '"><label for="' . esc_attr( $field['id'] ) . '">' . wp_kses_post( $field['label'] ) . '</label><select id="' . esc_attr( $field['id'] ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $field['name'] ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( $field['class'] ) . '" multiple="multiple">';

    foreach ( $field['options'] as $key => $value ) {

        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" ' . ( in_array( $key, $field['value'] ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';

    }

    echo '</select> ';

    if ( ! empty( $field['description'] ) ) {

        if ( isset( $field['desc_tip'] ) && false !== $field['desc_tip'] ) {
            echo '<img class="help_tip" data-tip="' . esc_attr( $field['description'] ) . '" src="' . esc_url( WC()->plugin_url() ) . '/assets/images/help.png" height="16" width="16" />';
        } else {
            echo '<span class="description">' . wp_kses_post( $field['description'] ) . '</span>';
        }

    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Example of how to use the function:

```
woocommerce_wp_select_multiple( array(
    'id' => 'newoptions',
    'name' => 'newoptions[]',
    'class' => 'newoptions',
    'label' => __('Testing Multiple Select', 'woocommerce'),
    'options' => array(
        '1' => 'User1',
        '2' => 'User2',
        '3' => 'User3',
    ))
);
```

Comment: @Danijel How can we alter the save function for this custom field. I have a location field where user can select multiple locations. How would i save two meta values with the same key ?

Comment: I did it by serializing the `$_POST['newoptions'];`

Answer (score 10):

It is not necessary to create a new function. The `woocommerce_wp_select` handles this out of the box. One of the attributes available is the `custom_attributes` which can accept an array. If you pass in an `array('multiple'=>'multiple)` then it renders a multiselect. In order to serialize and handle the input, you just provide a `name[]` in the name field and it works like magic. Here is an example -

```
woocommerce_wp_select(
    array(
        'id' => '_cb_days_available',
        'name' => '_cb_days_available[]',
        'label' => __('Days Offered', 'woocommerce'),
        'description' => 'Which days of the week is this charter available?',
        'default' => get_option('cb_open_days'),
        'desc_tip' => 'true',
        'class' => 'cb-admin-multiselect',
        'options' => array(
            'Mon' => 'Monday',
            'Tue' => 'Tuesday',
            'Wed' => 'Wednesday',
            'Thu' => 'Thursday',
            'Fri' => 'Friday',
            'Sat' => 'Saturday',
            'Sun' => 'Sunday'
        ),
        'custom_attributes' => array('multiple' => 'multiple')
    )
);
```