# Custom checkbox in product settings that displays a custom field when checked

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am currently working on a WordPress eCommerce website, using WooCommerce.

I have created a custom Checkbox within the Product edit pages general settings.

I have also a code snippet that is displaying a custom text field in single product pages.

Now I would like when this  custom Checkbox is checked for a product (in it's settings), to display this custom text field in single product pages.

**The Coding I have so far:**

To create the Checkbox, within the WooCommerce Product Dashboard, I have entered the following code into the `functions.php` file:

```
<?php
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');

// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');


function woocommerce_product_custom_fields(){
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id'          => '_custom_product_checkbox_field',
            'placeholder' => 'Custom Product Checkbox Field',
            'label'       => __('Custom Product Checkbox Field', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip'    => 'true'
        )
    );
echo '</div>';

}

// Saving Values
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $woocommerce_custom_product_checkbox_field = $_POST['_custom_product_checkbox_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_checkbox_field ))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_checkbox_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_custom_product_checkbox_field ));
}
?>
```

The coding I have placed, in the `functions.php` file, as to Output the relevant Custom Text Box, is as follows:

```
function add_engrave_text_field() {
    if (is_single('product-url-a')) {
        echo 'Enter your chosen letters:  <span id="character_count"></span>
        <div><table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="value"><label class="product-custom-text-label" for="custom_text">Custom Text</label></td>
                    <td class="value">
                        <label><input type="text" class="product-counter" name="engrave_text" placeholder="Enter Your Custom Letters ..." maxlength="3" /></label>                        
                    </td>
                </tr>                             
            </tbody>
        </table></div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_engrave_text_field', 0 );
```

What would be my next step, so that the Custom Text Box coding will only be Outputted when the Checkbox is selected?

I realise that I could put the code for the Custom Text Box into the `content-single-product`, however I would ideally not want to do this as it is part of a large group of coding which works out the pricing of the Custom Lettering etc.

**Additional Question:**

The website is made up of 5 Product Categories.  Only Products in one of these Categories allow for Custom Lettering.  At present, I am having to manually apply the above coding to each individual product, as I am having to insert the individual slugs into `if (is_single('product-slug-a'))`  Is there a way I could change 'product-slug-a' so that I only have to enter the code once into the `functions.php` file and it is called for every Product within just one of the Product Categories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:**

I have revisited a bit your code, simplifying things, removing unnecessary code. I  have added the necessary code to make this "Engraving field" to be displayed on single product pages only when the checkbox setting option has been checked.

> For your last question check at the end *(for a product category without checkbox settings)*.

Here is the code:

```
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'product_custom_fields_add');
function product_custom_fields_add(){
    global $post;

    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';

    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox( array(
        'id'        => '_engrave_text_option',
        'desc'      => __('set custom Engrave text field', 'woocommerce'),
        'label'     => __('Display custom Engrave text field', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'  => 'true'
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'product_custom_fields_save');
function product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
    // Custom Product Text Field
    $engrave_text_option = isset( $_POST['_engrave_text_option'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_engrave_text_option', esc_attr( $engrave_text_option ));
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_engrave_text_field', 0 );
function add_engrave_text_field() {
    global $post;

    // If is single product page and have the "engrave text option" enabled we display the field
    if ( is_product() && get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_engrave_text_option', true ) == 'yes' ) {

        ?>
        <div>
            <label class="product-custom-text-label" for="engrave_text"><?php _e( 'Engraving option:', 'woocommerce'); ?><br>
                <input style="min-width:220px" type="text" class="product-counter" name="engrave_text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter Your Custom Letters ...', 'woocommerce'); ?>" maxlength="3" />
            </label>
        </div><br>
        <?php
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Checkbox output and save: [Adding programatically data option tab to admin product pages Metabox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007426/adding-programatically-data-option-tab-to-admin-product-pages-metabox/39010336#39010336)

You will get something like this when the checkbox option has been selected in the product settings:

[image]

---

Make it work **for a product category or a product tag** (**without settings checkbox**):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_engrave_text_field', 0 );
function add_engrave_text_field() {
    global $post;

    // HERE set the term Ids, slug or name (or an array of values)
    $categories = array( 'clothing', 'music' );

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat'; // (For product tags use 'product_tag' instead)

    // If is single product page and have the "engrave text option" enabled we display the field
    if ( is_product() && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ) {

        ?>
        <div>
            <label class="product-custom-text-label" for="engrave_text"><?php _e( 'Engraving option:', 'woocommerce'); ?><br>
                <input style="min-width:220px" type="text" class="product-counter" name="engrave_text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Enter Your Custom Letters ...', 'woocommerce'); ?>" maxlength="3" />
            </label>
        </div><br>
        <?php
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Great.  Thank you for your detailed answer.  The code does work.  One minor question, however, is the term 'engrave' some kind of default with WooCommerce?  Whenever I replace all references of 'engrave' with 'custom', the Custom Text Box, disappears from the Product Page.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code.  Not sure why, but that seems to break the website.  Gonna see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Sorry if I am overlooking something simple.  To make sure that I didn't enter any typos, I simply copy and pasted the code into the `functions.php` file and it produces a white screen.

Comment: @Craig I have remove bugs, updated everything and optimized code… sorry I was tired yesterday. Now why are you using a check box, as you could use a woocommerce product category or a product tag for this… So to enable the custom field for a product you should just need to enable the related product category or tag? => like in the last snippet code

Comment: Hope you slept well. Thank you for the code.  I have managed to get the code working.  I just have a final problem saving empty Value when using `woocommerce_wp_text_input`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47487995/how-can-i-save-empty-values-in-a-custom-text-field But that is another question.  You have been helpful :-)

Comment: @Craig I have answer your other question…